# Registering endpoints - Member must not be null (Service: AmazonSNS;

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, amazon-sns

Testing on android 4.2.2, API 17 (simulated). This works with API 21+ (hard and simulated devices).

> Caused by: com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException: 1 validation error
>   detected: Value null at 'token' failed to satisfy constraint: Member
>   must not be null (Service: AmazonSNS; Status Code: 400; Error Code:
>   ValidationError; Request ID:

Using firebase token to register a device endpoint (to AWS SNS) with method below and getting error above. It fails on line

```
    CreatePlatformEndpointResult cpeRes = client.createPlatformEndpoint(cpeReq);
```

Method:

```
private String createEndpoint() {
    String endpointArn = null;
    try {
        System.out.println("Creating platform endpoint with token " + token);
        CreatePlatformEndpointRequest cpeReq =
                new CreatePlatformEndpointRequest()
                        .withPlatformApplicationArn(applicationArn)
                        .withToken(token);
        CreatePlatformEndpointResult cpeRes = client.createPlatformEndpoint(cpeReq);
        endpointArn = cpeRes.getEndpointArn();
    } catch (Exception ipe) {
        String message = ipe.toString();
        System.out.println("Exception message: " + message);
        Pattern p = Pattern
                .compile(".*Endpoint (arn:aws:sns[^ ]+) already exists " +
                        "with the same token.*");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(message);
        if (m.matches()) {
            // The platform endpoint already exists for this token, but with
            endpointArn = m.group(1);
        } else {
            // Rethrow the exception, the input is actually bad.
            throw ipe;
        }
    }
    storeEndpointArn(endpointArn);
    return endpointArn;
}
```

Comment: Did you verify that the token is not null and formatted the way you expect it to? Also, how did you init the client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after hours of playing with the code, the problem is not with the code, but with the emulator.

[Google Play Services](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup)

> To develop an app using the Google Play services APIs, you need to set
>   up your project with the Google Play services SDK.
>
> If you haven't installed the Google Play services SDK yet, go get it
>   now by following the guide to Adding SDK Packages.
>
> To test your app when using the Google Play services SDK, you must use
>   either:
>
> A compatible Android device that runs Android 2.3 or higher and
>   includes Google Play Store. The Android emulator with an AVD that runs
>   the Google APIs platform based on Android 4.2.2 or higher.

So on [API 17](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/understanding_android_api_levels/)...

> API 17 (**Android 4.2-4.2.2**) – Jelly Bean, released November 2012. Build
>   version code Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.JellyBeanMr1

So, to emulate this on API 17 and up, open the SDK installer, and show package details. In the API version to be emulated, install all packages relating to Google APIs. [This](http://engblog.yext.com/post/android-emulation) gives you an idea.

[image]